# How are Python modules (which are shared libraries) imported without a .py file?

Tags: python-2.7, python-import

I am running an interactive Python shell and trying to see the path from which a module is being imported using the 'inspect' module. The modules I am trying to import have Python wrappers around C++ APIs using SWIG.

The following snippet shows my steps :

```
>>> import os
>>> import inspect
>>>      
>>> import db
>>> inspect.getfile(db)
'mypath1/lib/db/db.pyc'
>>>
>>> import dart
>>> inspect.getfile(dart)
'mypath2/lib/dart.so'
>>>
```

My `PYTHONPATH` contains both `mypath1/lib/db`  and `mypath2/lib`.

I was under the impression that in order to be able to load modules, the interpreter needs access to a `.py` file which then calls `imp.load_module` to load the required shared library (`.so` file). This is what I see in case of the `db` module which has a `db.py` file under `mypath1/lib/db`. However, `dart` does not have a `.py` file under `mypath2/lib`.

Is it possible to import a module without the .py file as is happening in the case of the `dart` module ?

Answer (score 12):

Python searches for several different files for any given `import` including a directory by that name and containing an `__init__.py`, an `.so` file for pure-native Python modules and `.pyc` files which can be used even if the `.py` is removed.

Run `strace -o trace_output.txt python` to see how this works.  Partial example for `import md5`:

```
stat("/usr/lib/python2.7/md5", 0x7fff81ff16d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/md5.x86_64-linux-gnu.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/md5.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/md5module.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/md5.py", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

On my setup, it actually searches:

- `~/.local/lib/python2.7/`
- `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`
- `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`
- `/usr/lib/python2.7/`

Within each directory, the pattern of calling `stat` to find a directory then looking for `.so` files, then `.py` is followed.

For more info on writing a purely native python module, see here:  https://docs.python.org/2/extending/index.html